# XSLT to limit the number of child nodes under a parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry but a total xslt noob here

Given XML that looks like:

```
<Foo>
  <Bar />
  <Baz />
  <Qax />
  <FooBar />
</Foo>
```

Is there an XSLT that will limit the number of child nodes under Foo so that there are only 3?

Comment: In which sense "limit"? Which elements you want exclude? Any under three?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete short and easy solution that uses one of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns -- the overriding of the identity rule.

Comment: I also provided detailed explanation.

Comment: A reference to the identity rule design pattern is now also included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation uses and overrides the identity rule/template:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[position() > 3]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Foo>
    <Bar />
    <Baz />
    <Qax />
    <FooBar />
</Foo>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Foo>
   <Bar/>
   <Baz/>
   <Qax/>
</Foo>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)/template copies every node "as-is".**
2. **We have just one additional template that overrides the identity rule for any element that is a child of the top element with position greater than 3**. This template dos nothing (has an empty body), which effectively prevents any such element from being copied to the output (or as we use to say, "deletes" it).

**Do note**:

1. **Using and overriding the identity rule is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern**.
2. **Using this design pattern is recommended over a simple `<xsl:copy-of>`,** because it allows the nodes not only to be copied, but to be processed by any template we provide. Attributes of all elements are also processed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/Foo">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[position()&lt;4]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gets:

```
<Foo>
   <Bar/>
   <Baz/>
   <Qax/>
</Foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of doing this:

Firstly, you can instruct the template that handles the `Foo` element to only process the first three child nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="Foo">
  <xsl:copy> <!-- can substitute with 'Foo' in this instance -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() &lt;= 3]" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if the first three child nodes don't need any individual treatment, you can use a template like this to handle the children:

```
<xsl:template match="Foo/*[position() &lt;= 3]">
  <!-- process the child element here -->
</xsl:template>
```

The two downsides to this approach are that the remaining children of `Foo` can be processed by other templates, for example if you had one for specifically handling `FooBar` nodes, and also there's no easy way of treating your `Bar` and `Baz` elements differently.

The third method is to use an empty template that is applied to all child nodes of `Foo` after the third one like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Foo/*[position() &gt; 3]" />
```

This method also gives you the advantage of being able to apply individual templates for `Bar` and `Baz` if you need to.